# Python script in R reticulate: Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : SystemExit: 2

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have a Python script that I want to use in my R code (to calculate a certain amount of precipitation at specified location (coordinate)).

I already used this code:

```
setwd('C:/Users/username/Documents')
library(reticulate)
reticulate::source_python("raster_extract.py")
```

but this turns into the error

```
usage: python.exe [-h] [--coords COORDS [COORDS ...]] [--input INPUT] [--odim]
                  [--band BAND] [--output OUTPUT] [--writer WRITER]
                  [--decimals DECIMALS]
                  path [path ...]
python.exe: error: the following arguments are required: path
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : SystemExit: 2
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
```

I looked up on the internet what this error could mean, but nothing could help me so far. I'm stuck on it for quite a long time. Is there someone who can tell me why I'm not able to integrate this Python code into my R script?

Comment: Without  reprex (reproducible example), it's difficult to answer. It's maybe an issue of local path. Try something like `reticulate::source_python(file.path(getwd(),"yourpath","yoursubpath","raster_extract.py"))` . An other issue could be the path to python.exe. Do you use `anaconda` ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using anaconda. Probably the error occurred because I was trying this in a Windows environment. I'm now using the Powershell and the problem seems fixed. Thanks anyway for your answer.